# Extracting specific strings patterns from one column

Tags: r, regex, string

I would like to extract specific strings with the pattern `gene=something` from one column in R.

An example of input:

```
df <- 'V1 
       ID=gene92;DbX;gene=BH1;genePro
       ID=gene91;DbY;gene=BH2;genePro;inf2
       ID=gene90;DbY;gene=BH3;genePro;inf2'
df <- read.table(text=df, header=T)
```

The example of the expected output:

```
dfout <- 'V1 
         gene=BH1
         gene=BH2
         gene=BH3'
    dfout <- read.table(text=dfout, header=T)
```

Some idea to accomplish that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may also use

```
gsub(".*(gene=.*?)(;|$).*", "\\1", df$V1)
# [1] "gene=BH1" "gene=BH2" "gene=BH3"
```

so that we match only the part `gene=...` that follows anything, `.*`,  and is followed by `;` or the end of the string, `;|$`.

Answer (score 4):

```
library(stringr)
str_extract(df$V1, 'gene=BH[0-9]+')
#[1] "gene=BH1" "gene=BH2" "gene=BH3"
```

Comment: Assuming gene names could be variable and not always be BH and number, you could try `str_extract(df$v1, 'gene=(.*?);')` and `gsub` out that semicolon?

Comment: I just went with the example. It can of course be more generalized via `sub`